# My javascript Program comparing 2 numbers keeps returning error

Tags: javascript, function

[image]I am trying to write a function that takes 2 numbers and returns the bigger one but I keep getting error module.js540 throw err.

```
function largerThan(a,b){
    if(a > b) {
        return a;
    }else {
        return b;
    }
}
var biggerNumber = largerThan(1,2);
console.log(biggerNumber)
```

Comment: would be helpful if you shared your error with us

Comment: That error message is unrelated to the `largerThan` function

Answer (score 4):

`return var biggerNumber = a` is a syntax error

You're looking for:

`return a`

Comment: I still keep getting the error module.js540 throw err;

Comment: @ThomasP Like we are supposed to know what module.js540 is.... Did you also fix `return b`? Can you post the full error message and what is on that line?

Answer (score 0):

```
function largerThan(a,b){
    if(a > b) {
        return a;
    }else {
        return b
    }
}
var biggerNumber = largerThan(1,2);
console.log(biggerNumber)
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing a 'variable declaration' statement and a 'return' statement.

The code should look like this:

```
function largerThan(a,b) {
  if(a > b) {
   return a;
  }else {
   return b;
  }
}
var biggerNumber = largerThan(1,2);
```

If *b* is the larger number, then the function will return the value in *b*.  The statement "var biggerNumber = largerThan(1,2)" will store the value that the function returned to your variable.